# How to validate ksql script?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I would like to know if there is a way for checking if a `.ksql` script is syntactically correct?

I know that you can send a `POST` request to the server, this however would also execute the containing ksql commands. I would love to have some kind of endpoint where you can pass your statement and it returns you either an error code or an OK like:

`curl -XPOST <ksqldb-server>/ksql/validate -d '{"ksql": "<ksql-statement>"}'` .

My question aims for a way to check the synatx in an automated fashion without the need to cleaning up everything afterwards.

Thanks for you help!

Note: I am also well aware that I could run everything separately using, e.g., a `docker-compose` file and tear everything down again. This however is quite resource heavy and and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

one option could be to use the ksql test runner (see here: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/test-an-app/) and look at the errors to check if the statement is valid. Let me know if it works for your scenario.

Comment: One problem I have with the ksql-test-runner is that I cannot make assumptions on how the `.ksql` will look like, so defining an input/output file is not really possible. The most concrete assumptions I can have is how the topics are called. Although I like this test-runner and will try to make use of it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By now I've found a way to test for my use case. I had a ksqldb cluster already in place with all other systems needed for the Kafka ecosystem (Zookeeper, Broker,...). I had to compromise a little but and go through the effort of deploying everything but here is my approach:

1. Use proper naming (let it be prefixed with `test` or whatever suits your use case) for your streams, tables,... the queries' sink property should include the prefixed topic in order to find it easily, or you simply assign an QUERY_ID (https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/6553).
2. Deploy the streams, tables,... to your ksqldb server using its rest API. Since I was programming in Python, I made use of the `ksql` package using `pip` (https://github.com/bryanyang0528/ksql-python).
3. Cleanup the ksqldb server by filtering for the naming that you assigned to the ksql resources and run the corresponding `DROP` or `TERMINATE` statement. Consider also, you will have dependencies that result in multiple streams/tables reusing a topics. The statements can be looked up in the official developer guide (https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/quick-reference/).
4. If you had errors in step 2, step 3 should have cleaned up the leftovers so that you can adjust your `ksql` scripts until they run through smoothly.

Note: I could not make any assumptions on how the streams,... look like. If you can, I would prefer the `ksql-test-runner`.